# Calculating Change in OR per increase from the 25th to 75th percentile (IQR)

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, interquartile

I have a dichotomous outcome variable (ever disease) and a continuous exposure variable (chemical). I have already run the logistic regression for the ln exposure and gotten the odds ratio. However, because this exposure is fairly common, a per 1-unit increase doesn't tell you a whole lot. Therefore, I wanted to see if there was a way that I could see the change per IQR increase in my exposure variable. Thank you!

Comment: Why not? Just do the multiplication.  Are you somehow limited in the information you have about the data?  If so, what information do you have?

Comment: Do you mean to compute the change in *odds* given the estimate of the *odds ratio*?